# Setting Up PHPUnit tests for WP development on Windows

Tags: php, wp-cli, unit-tests

I've been following the instructions in [this article](https://pippinsplugins.com/unit-tests-wordpress-plugins-setting-up-testing-suite/) to try to set up some testing.

I got as far as this instruction `bash bin/install-wp-tests.sh wordpress_test root 'mypass' localhost latest` before I hit some problems.

I have git bash installed so the command ran, but I got this error when I run`phpunit`:

`Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/tmp/wordpress-tests-lib/includes/functions.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\dev\robinandrews-wp\wp-content\plugins\plugin-testing\tests\bootstrap.php on line 14`

Not sure that include path looks right? If that's the prop how can I change it, and what to?

Any help much appreciated.

The output from the above command is:

```
+ install_wp
+ '[' -d /tmp/wordpress/ ']'
+ return
+ install_test_suite
++ uname -s
+ [[ MSYS_NT-10.0 == \D\a\r\w\i\n ]]
+ local ioption=-i
+ '[' '!' -d /tmp/wordpress-tests-lib ']'
+ '[' '!' -f wp-tests-config.php ']'
+ download https://develop.svn.wordpress.org/tags/4.7.3/wp-tests-config-sample.php /tmp/wordpress-tests-lib/wp-tests-config.php
++ which curl
+ '[' /mingw64/bin/curl ']'
+ curl -s https://develop.svn.wordpress.org/tags/4.7.3/wp-tests-config-sample.php
++ echo /tmp/wordpress/
++ sed 's:/\+$::'
+ WP_CORE_DIR=/tmp/wordpress
+ sed -i 's:dirname( __FILE__ ) . '\''/src/'\'':'\''/tmp/wordpress/'\'':' /tmp/wordpress-tests-lib/wp-tests-config.php
+ sed -i s/youremptytestdbnamehere/wordpress_test/ /tmp/wordpress-tests-lib/wp-tests-config.php
+ sed -i s/yourusernamehere/root/ /tmp/wordpress-tests-lib/wp-tests-config.php
+ sed -i s/yourpasswordhere/mysql/ /tmp/wordpress-tests-lib/wp-tests-config.php
+ sed -i 's|localhost|localhost|' /tmp/wordpress-tests-lib/wp-tests-config.php
+ install_db
+ '[' false = true ']'
+ PARTS=(${DB_HOST//\:/ })
+ local PARTS
+ local DB_HOSTNAME=localhost
+ local DB_SOCK_OR_PORT=
+ local EXTRA=
+ '[' -z localhost ']'
++ echo
++ grep -e '^[0-9]\{1,\}$'
+ '[' ']'
+ '[' -z ']'
+ '[' -z localhost ']'
+ EXTRA=' --host=localhost --protocol=tcp'
+ mysqladmin create wordpress_test --user=root --password=mypass --host=localhost --protocol=tcp
```

Comment: That command is assuming *nix, I think, so the fact that you are on Windows is probably what fouled things up. It was attempting to add set up the WordPress test suite in `/tmp/wordpress-tests-lib`, but apparently that didn't happen correctly—or, maybe it did, but you need to modify the include path in `robinandrews-wp\wp-content\plugins\plugin-testing\tests\bootstrap.php` on line 14, to be Windows compatible (`C:\tmp\wordpress-tests-lib`?). You might try setting up something with Vagrant instead, like [VVV](https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV).